# How can I get the current bot status?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been trying for hours to fix an issue and I really don't know how.
Maybe you can help me:
I tried pretty much everything i could find on the internet to get the status, but everything returned either an error (could not read property status of client/bot), an undefined answer or 0 everytime.

```js
bot.on("message", async message => {

    if(message.author.bot) {
        return;
    }

    if(message.channel.type === "dm") {

        if (bot.status == "DND") {

            message.author.sendMessage("[AUTOMATISCHE NACHRICHT] Hey! Dadurch dass ich gerade zu tun habe, werde ich dir zurückschreiben, sobald ich Zeit habe :)")
            console.log(`[DM] ${message.author.username} wrote via DM.`)
            console.log("Du bist auf DND")

    }}
})
```

I need to check, what status the bot is currently in (dnd, online, offline, idle, ...)
I couldn't find anything that helped in the discord.js documentation

I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance :)

Edit:
It's not rather an error, but i need to know, how i can check the bot's current status.
The link above is everything of the code that matters.
So: it's not working

Comment: @ThomasReichmann i edited the post a bit, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To check a user's status using discord.js you can go to the [Presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence) class within [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser), so you would need something like `bot.user.presence.status`

As stated in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceStatus) this status is a string that can either be:

- **online** - user is online
- **idle** - user is AFK
- **offline** - user is offline or invisible
- **dnd** - user is in Do Not Disturb

And do take care to not have problems with upper and lower case, since in your code you check for `"DND"` and not `"dnd"`.

Comment: Yeah, that was because i was playing around  and trying if It'd work. It works now, thank you very much!